# Relative clause\ non-defining

Tags: grammar

Relative clause non-defining  ( It means adding extra information using commas )

I know the relative pronoun ( that ) is only used in the defining relative clause, but here it is not a relative pronoun in the way I answered it.

Combine the sentences to make a non-defining relative clause :

> The museum was closed when we went there. That was disappointing.

"*That was disappointing*" expresses sorrow. Here ( that) is used just to start the speech

My answer:

> That was disappointing we went there, when the museum was closed.

I think there is not another possible way.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a relative clause that describes the sentence as a whole. Such relative clauses are always non-defining, so you would use "which" and move it to the end of the sentence:

> The museum was closed when we went there, **which** was disappointing.

Comment: I think my answer is still good or acceptable  ((  That was disappointing we went there, when the museum was closed. ))    Why to remove that  ?  In my sentence ( that ) = demonstrative

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. "That was disappointing we went there" contains two main verbs ("was" and "went") and your sentence does not have a relative clause, since "that" is being used as a demonstrative.

Answer (score 1):

The form suggested in [the answer by alphabet](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/332557/91457):

> The museum was closed when we went there, **which** was disappointing.

is perhaps the most obvious way to combine the two sentences.  But they can also be combined using a defining clause, for example:

> It was disappointing **that** the museum was closed when we went there.

In this version the clause after "*that*" defines just **what** was disappointing. This version places more emphasis on the emotion of disappointment, and comparatively less on the event that caused it. But the meaning is much the same.

---

A comment by the OP suggests the alternative:

> That was disappointing we went there, when the museum was closed. [image: Red X, showing incorrect form]

This is not grammatically valid. A somewhat similar, but valid sentence would be:

> It was disappointing that we went there when the museum was closed. [image: Green Check mark, showing a valid form]

Another possibility would be:

> It was disappointing that when we went there the museum was closed. [image: Green Check mark, showing a valid form]

Neither of these is using a non-defining relative clause, however.

Comment: Your second example does not contain a relative clause. "That the museum was closed when we went there" is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "disappointing".

Comment: Yep. The "that..." clause is really the subject of "was," but it gets moved to the end of the sentence because of it-extraposition.

Comment: @ David Siegel , when it is a non-defining relative clause, you should insert commas.  There is not a non-defining relative clause without commas and hence, you answer = not correct    In your sentence, ( that ) = conjunction, it can mean ( because )   I think my answer is still good or acceptable  ((  That was disappointing we went there, when the museum was closed. ))

Comment: @Ahmad Mohammad Commas are normally usewd to set off non-defining relative clauses, but the grammar controls the commas, the presence or absence of commas does not change the grammar. Your suggested sentence is certainly not normal English, and I think is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Ahmad Mohammad  see the added section of my answer for a fuller response.

Comment: It does not change meaning  yes  but commas must be added.  If no commas are added then no difference or nothing can help to say whether relative pronoun is necessary or not necessary     >> I thank you for your first answer and  I myself voted to, but it maybe I am not satisfied to omit a word  which is  (( that )) ?